# All I want to do is display an asci string in a Panel widget and retain its formatting/color

Tags: python, widget, ascii, panel, pygments

All I want to do is display an asci string in a Panel widget and retain its formatting/color.

**What I Want:**

```
#here's the string after pygments formatting:
test = '\x1b[38;2;0;68;221mTraceback (most recent call last):\x1b[39m\n  File \x1b[38;2;0;128;0m"<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>"\x1b[39m, line \x1b[38;2;102;102;102m17\x1b[39m, in <module>\n    myfunc(\x1b[38;2;102;102;102m3\x1b[39m)\n  File \x1b[38;2;0;128;0m"<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>"\x1b[39m, line \x1b[38;2;102;102;102m6\x1b[39m, in myfunc\n    \x1b[38;2;0;128;0;01mreturn\x1b[39;00m myfunc(x\x1b[38;2;102;102;102m-\x1b[39m\x1b[38;2;102;102;102m1\x1b[39m)\n  File \x1b[38;2;0;128;0m"<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>"\x1b[39m, line \x1b[38;2;102;102;102m6\x1b[39m, in myfunc\n    \x1b[38;2;0;128;0;01mreturn\x1b[39;00m myfunc(x\x1b[38;2;102;102;102m-\x1b[39m\x1b[38;2;102;102;102m1\x1b[39m)\n  File \x1b[38;2;0;128;0m"<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>"\x1b[39m, line \x1b[38;2;102;102;102m6\x1b[39m, in myfunc\n    \x1b[38;2;0;128;0;01mreturn\x1b[39;00m myfunc(x\x1b[38;2;102;102;102m-\x1b[39m\x1b[38;2;102;102;102m1\x1b[39m)\n  File \x1b[38;2;0;128;0m"<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>"\x1b[39m, line \x1b[38;2;102;102;102m5\x1b[39m, in myfunc\n    \x1b[38;2;0;128;0;01massert\x1b[39;00m x \x1b[38;2;102;102;102m>\x1b[39m \x1b[38;2;102;102;102m0\x1b[39m, \x1b[38;2;186;33;33m"\x1b[39m\x1b[38;2;186;33;33moh no\x1b[39m\x1b[38;2;186;33;33m"\x1b[39m\n\x1b[38;2;255;0;0mAssertionError\x1b[39m: oh no\n'

#I want it to look like this in Panel:
print(test)
```

**What I Have:**

```
#The closest I can get is:
import panel as pn
string_b4_pygments = 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>", line 17, in <module>\n    myfunc(3)\n  File "<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>", line 6, in myfunc\n    return myfunc(x-1)\n  File "<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>", line 6, in myfunc\n    return myfunc(x-1)\n  File "<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>", line 6, in myfunc\n    return myfunc(x-1)\n  File "<ipython-input-3-39b4fbfd5961>", line 5, in myfunc\n    assert x > 0, "oh no"\nAssertionError: oh no\n'
pn.pane.Str(string_b4_pygments)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that capturing the error and formatting it as an html instead of asci did the trick.  E.g.

```
import panel as pn
import traceback as tb
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import Python3TracebackLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
pn.extension()

def myfunc(x):
   assert x > 0, "oh no"
   return myfunc(x-1)

def extract_format_tb_html(e):
    traceback_str = ''.join(tb.format_exception(None, e, e.__traceback__))
    return highlight(traceback_str, Python3TracebackLexer(), HtmlFormatter(noclasses=True))

try:
    myfunc(3)
except Exception as e:
    test = extract_format_tb_html(e)

pn.pane.Str(test)
```